# How to store result from SQLPlus to a shell variable

Tags: shell, unix, sqlplus

My requirement is to store the result of an sqlplus operation into a variable in my shell script.
I need the result of the following operation which is in my .sh file

```
sqlplus 'user/pwd' @test.sql
```

I have already tried

```
testvar = 'sqlplus 'user/pwd'
@test.sql'
```

but that doesn't work.

## EDIT::

I changed it to

```
testvar=sqlplus foo/bar@SCHM @test.sql
```

and it says

> `SQL*Plus:: not found [No such file or directory]`

I tried with

```
testvar=$(sqlplus foo/bar@SCHM
@test.sql)
```

and it gives the same error.
When I try without the variable assignment like below

```
sqlplus foo/bar@schm @test.sql
```

it works fine

Comment: In a Bourne-type shell (such as bash), the syntax does not allow for spaces around the `=`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Employ backticks:

```
testvar=`sqlplus foo/bar @test.sql`
```

or should that be of syntactical eyesore:

```
testvar=$(sqlplus foo/bar @test.sql)
```

You clearly know to take the right sql*plus commands to limit superfluous output, yes? :) and of course beware the backticking will collapse the whitespace of the output.

Comment: "the backticking will collapse the whitespace of the output" -- it won't. It will just remove trailing newlines. Also, there's nothing old-schoolish in using `$()`, it's rather the other way round.

Comment: It's the other way around: backticks are "old school". The whitespace is not lost on assignment. It is lost on output if the variable isn't quoted.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about `$()` I did actually edit later to add the other option and forgot to switch around.

Comment: I made it testvar=`sqlplus foo/bar@SCHM @test.sql` and it says SQL*Plus:: not found [No such file or directory] i tried with testvar=$(sqlplus foo/bar@SCHM @test.sql) and it gives the same error. When I try without the variable assignment like sqlplus foo/bar@schm @test.sql it works fine

Comment: PATH and ORACLE_HOME exported?

Answer (score 19):

Try this instead:

```
testvar=`sqlplus -s foo/bar@SCHM <<EOF
set pages 0
set head off
set feed off
@test.sql
exit
EOF`
```

-s switch will turn off all the header info when sqlplus launches. You also want to turn off the feedback, headers, and pagesize to 0.  I am old school so I still use the back ticks :)

Comment: should add verify off , in case of passing parameters

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a syntax like this. I didn't want to use a sql file.

Answer (score 1):

As commands within `$()` are executed in a subshell, make sure you have everything you need for the invocation of sqlplus exported. Right now you obviously stumbled into the `PATH` issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions here are all hacks.

Your sql file should look like this...

```
set termout off
set showmode off
set heading off
set echo off
set timing off
set time off
set feedback 0
set pagesize 0
set embedded ON
set verify OFF

spool courses.sh
SELECT 'term="' || sfrstcr_term_code || '";', 'subj="' || sfrstcr_subj_code || '";' FROM sfrstcr WHERE sfrstcr_pidm = 1234567;
spool off
```

The following shell script will read and print out the shell environment variables.

```
while read -r row; do
  eval "$row"
  echo "term=$term"; 
  echo "subj=$subj"; 
done < courses.sh
```

It's important that all the variables are on one line, as the read command ensures that you can read each DB row per loop.

Comment: @trenton-d-adams  termout off - mean  no display to terminal . I think it better to leave it on , unless you use spool command