# Use PL/SQL variable as a shell variable

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql

I have a PL/SQL program which is run using a bash script. Now, I want the a variable of that PL/SQL program to a shell variable so that I can perform some operations. I tried the following but it did not work.

```
su - oracle -c "sqlplus << EOF

connect / as sysdba

set serveroutput on size 30000;

VARIABLE RET NUMBER;

DECLARE
tab_count number;

BEGIN

select count(*) into tab_count from all_tables where owner='scott';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10)||'Count: '||tab_count);
:RET:=tab_count;

END;
/
EXIT:RET

EOF"


echo $RET
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953842/how-to-store-result-from-sqlplus-to-a-shell-variable

Comment: @AndreGelinas How can i put the whole of the command in a variable? I tried, but I am getting error with formatting. I tried putting testvar=' su - oracle '.. but got error

Comment: Let say you have ScriptA.sh which is your main script. Somewhere in ScriptA you do RET=$( /foo/bar/ScriptB.sh ). ScriptB.sh is the script containing the PL/SQL proc returning the value you want. Then ScriptA continue processing with that value in the variable RET. At least that's the way I understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 1 way, there might be others.

I save the variable RET to a NEW_VALUE then use HOST to write a set value script, which you would then source.

See the additions I have made, enclosed by the `"-- New bit"` and `"--End new bit"` comments, and the `ret_val.sh` call at the end.

```
su - oracle -c "sqlplus << EOF

connect / as sysdba

set serveroutput on size 30000;

VARIABLE RET NUMBER;

DECLARE
tab_count number;

BEGIN

select count(*) into tab_count from all_tables where owner='scott';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10)||'Count: '||tab_count);
:RET:=tab_count;

END;
/

-- New bit here - we're going to write out to a shell script to set the
-- value of RET to the required value

col RET NEW_VALUE RET
SELECT :RET RET FROM DUAL;
HOST echo "export RET='&r'" > ret_val.sh
-- End new bit
enter code here
EXIT

EOF"

# The ret_val.sh will have "export RET='retvalue'", so we just source this

. ret_val.sh    

echo $RET
```